# How to delete using joined value

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I came across two tables something like this

**product** table -

| id | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 |
| 2 | product2 |

**product_inventory** table -

| product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 9 |

the **product_inventory** tables *product_id* supposed to reference **product** tables *id* but let's say it doesn't so we have a product_id (and quantity) in *Product inventory* table that's not associated with any real product. Now imagine there are hundred thousands of invalid values like this so I can't manually remove them by id. So I find these using right joining both tables like this:

```
SELECT  product.id, product_inventory.product_id
    FROM  product
    RIGHT JOIN  product_inventory  ON product.id=product_inventory.product_id
    where  product.id is NULL;
```

so I get list of like this for example

| product.id | product_inventory.product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| NULL | 9 |

so how do I delete from **product_inventory** table where product.id is NULL?

Comment: A multi-table `DELETE` similar to your `SELECT` would probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
delete pi from product_inventory pi
    where not exists (select 1 from product p where p.id = pi.product_id);
```

You should also learn about foreign key relationships to prevent this from happening.